# Webpack and Yarn Workspace / Lerna

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, lerna

I have switched my lerna settings to use Yarn Workspace. Now I have a root node_modules with all packages dependancies. The node_modules in each package only has a .bin folder.

With this settings, webpack can't resolve dependancies. I need to change my config file like this :

```
resolve: {
  symlinks: false, <-- +
  modules: [
    helpers.getPath('src'),
    helpers.getPath('node_modules'),
    helpers.getPath('../../node_modules'),  <-- +
  ]
  ...others settings...
}
```

Two questions about this settings :

- Why I need to add the symlinks property ? I have much error without.
- Is is this the normal behavior with workspace to add a relative resolver in webpack (I have some packages wrapped in a dotnet solution, I need to add a very long relative path like ../../../../../../node_modules) ?

Comment: What's your directory structure look like? Where is Webpack located?

Answer (score -2):

```
resolve: {
  modules:['/path/to/src', 'node_modules']
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in what ways your code snippet answers the question?